# “\n” not adding new line when saving the string to text using BufferWriter to text file

Tags: java, file

Hi everyone I am trying to add a new line of string into an existing file, however the code i have appends it to the last string instead. I fixed it by adding a new line character to the string appending to the file, is there another way to append a string on a new line at the end of a file without adding the new line character to the beginning of the string?

```
String name = "\nbob";
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("names.txt",true));
    out.write(name);
    out.close();
```

current file:

```
bill
joe
john
```

after append

```
bill
joe
john
bob
```

append without newline

```
bill
joe
johnbob
```

Comment: Paraphrasing your question: *"Is there a way to append a new line without adding the new line character?"* **No.** If *you* don't add it, where else did you envision it would come from?

Comment: Title is a bit confusing because as you describe it, `\n` does the new line, but the title says does it doesn't

Comment: @guenhter yes and no, it is not completly cross-platform

Comment: It is always good to check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) before every question you ask. These are extremely useful, and answer a lot of questions you may have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\n` will be appended to your file here; but clearly you're just viewing it in such a way that you think there's no newline.

If you're working on Windows, `\n` isn't the correct line separator: use `\r\n` instead:

```
String name = "\r\nbob";
```

Windows uses `\r\n` as its line separator; and tools like Notepad (still) don't handle non-Windows line endings correctly.

Note that using `out.newLine()` is not necessarily the correct approach: this means that the current platform's line separator will be used. That *might* be correct; but if you're running this code on *nix, and the original file was generated on Windows (and has to continue to be readable correctly on Windows), it will not be, because `\n` will be used. "Write once, run anywhere" doesn't quite work here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [newLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()) methor prior to writing the new name out to file.

Answer (score 0):

It is use Java 7. BufferedWritter class provide newLine() method for break new line. You can follow this example. [example link](https://github.com/w3farid/IOExample/tree/dev)

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class BufferedWriterDemo {
    //file path
    private static final String FILENAME = "/home/farid/Desktop/bw.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //BufferedWriter api        //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME))) {
            String str = "This is the content to write into file";
            //write method
            bw.write(str);
            //break new line
            bw.newLine();
            String seconStr = "This is the content to write into file.";
            //write method
            bw.write(seconStr);
            //break new line
            bw.newLine();
            //console print message
            System.out.println("Successfully compeleted");
            //BufferedWritter close
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't explicitly close a resource opened by try-with-resources. At best it is redundant (the point of twr is that it's always closed); at worst, some resources might not support being closed twice.